# Logarithm and Lubin-Tate formal group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field, formal-groups

Let $K$ be a finite extension, by Milne's online note "class field theory", $m_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ has a natural $O_K$ module structure where the action is given by $[a]_f$. For such a $f$, there exists a unique formal group $F_f$ admitting $f$ as a endmorphism.
By [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_group_law#The_height_of_a_formal_group_law), the logarithm is a power series such that $\log(F(x,y))=\log(x)+\log(y)$. A pity is that Milne doesn't introduce the logarithm of a formal group.

Then the question is how to prove the following formula:
$$\log([a]_f(t))=a\log(t),$$where $a\in m_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ and $a\in O_K$.

The motivation is the proof of lemma 8 in [this paper](https://math.lionel.fourquaux.org/publications/lemfont.pdf) aiming at proving the existence of Lubin-Tate periods.

Thanks!

Comment: The logarithm $\log(T) = T + \ldots \in K[[T]]$ is the *unique* power series with the property that $\log(F(x,y)) = \log(x) + \log(y)$. (Proof: otherwise the additive group $\mathbf{G}_a$ over $K$ would have non-trivial automorphisms, which it doesn't). Let $P(x) = a^{-1} \log ([a]_f(x)) = a^{-1} \log(a x + \ldots) = x + \ldots$. Then, using the defining properties of $[a]_f$ and $\log$, we see
 that:

$$P(F(x,y)):= a^{-1} \log([a]_f F(x,y)) = a^{-1} \log(F([a]_f x,[a]_f y)) = a^{-1} \log([a]_f x) + a^{-1} \log([a]_f y) = P(x) + P(y),$$

so by uniqueness $P(x) = \log(x)$.

Comment: @user760870 This has clearly answered my question. Thanks very much.

Comment: Perhaps I’m reading something wrong, @user760870, but surely the additive group $\mathbf G_a$ has automorphisms: let $\lambda\in K^\times$, then $x\to\lambda x$ is an automorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was only five months later that I noticed this question. I’m sorry, but I find @user760870’s comment deficient, maybe even wrong.

Perhaps we might define a *prelogarithm* of the formal group $F$ defined over the field $K$ to be a $K$-series $g(x)$ such that $g(F(x,y))=g(x)+g(y)$. Then you see that if $\lambda\in K$, $\lambda g$ is also a prelogarithm of $F$, indeed that the set of prelogarithms is a $K$-vector space: you can add two to get another.

If $g\ne0$ is a prelogarithm, then let’s see that $g'(0)\ne0$. Indeed, if $g(x)\equiv ax^m\pmod{x^{m+1}}$, i.e. if $ax^m$ is the first nonzero term of $g(x)$, then you get $g(F(x,y))\equiv a(x+y)^m\equiv ax^m+ay^m\pmod{x^{m+1}}$, impossible unless $m=1$ *in characteristic zero*. This is why we don’t talk about characteristic-$p$ logarithms. And this is why $\{\text{prelogs of $F$}\}\to K$ by the rule $g\mapsto g'(0)$is an injection, even a surjection *if there is at least one nonzero prelogarithm*. That is, the set of prelogs is at most one-dimensional as a $K$-space. If one-dimensional, the unique prelog with $g'(0)=1$ is *the* logarithm of $F$, sometimes written $\log_F(x)$.

You do see immediately that if $[a]$ is an endomorphism of $F$, then $\log_F\circ[a]$ is a prelogarithm, and your question is answered.

It’s another issue to show that there is a nonzero prelogarithm. I prefer to do it by a degree-by-degree computation, but you may also take $F_1(0,x)$, that’s the derivative of $F$ with respect to the left-hand variable, then set that variable to zero, and substitute $x$ for the remaining $y$. Then integrate the reciprocal of that, and magically you’ll get the logarithm.

Comment: In your terminology, $a^{-1} \log ([a](x))$ and $\log(x)$ are both prelogarithm and the derivatives of them at $0$ are both $1$, so $a^{-1} \log ([a](x))=\log(x)$. @user760870 wants to use $\text{Aut}(G_a)\cong 1$ to prove the uniqueness, indeed $\text{Aut}(G_a)\cong K^*$ as a formal group over $K$ where $\text{char} K=0$.

Comment: You don’t even need to go to the formal category to get an automorphism group that big. I imagine that in the algebrogeometric category, the automorphisms of $\mathbf G_a$ are $\mathrm{GL}_1$, a groupscheme whose points with $K$ values are $K^\times$. Notice that in characteristic $p$, the endomorphisms of $\mathbf G_a$ form an immense ring, and an interesting one at that.